# What type of information does HTTPs make private from an ISP?

Tags: networking, https, isp, internet-security, privacy-protection

How private is HTTPs to an ISP?

For example, Can my ISP know the entire URL (Not only the domain) while connecting to a website with HTTPs? Can my ISP see images loaded through a website connected to HTTPs? Would my ISP know the subdomain I'm visiting through HTTPS?

Comment: See: [How much information can my ISP see?](http://superuser.com/questions/231991/how-much-information-can-my-isp-see)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can my ISP know the entire URL (Not only the domain) while connecting to a website with HTTPs?

- They will know/be able to log what IP you are accessing by virtue of TCP/IP packets traversing through the ISP.  The contents of the URL are encrypted, query strings and anything after the `https://domain.example/` cannot be seen.
- If you used your ISP's DNS servers to resovle the domain name in question, they are able to view/log this directly.
- If you used an third-party non-ISP DNS provider to resolve the domain name, they are able to view/log this in transit as standard DNS is not encrypted.  Some ISPs implement transparent proxying on standard DNS ports to prevent you from using a third-party DNS.

> Can my ISP see images loaded through a website connected to HTTPs?

No.  However, if the images are hosted on a separate domain, they can see the domain being accessed and the above applies.

> Would my ISP know the subdomain I'm visiting through HTTPS?

It's trivial to reverse-resolve an IP into the full domain name.

Comment: How is it trivial? Websites (domains) on a shared hosting share a single IP address.

Comment: You got me.  I didn't think about multiple hosts on a single IP.  It's trivial to reverse-resolve an IP into *a* full domain name--and a `whois` lookup on that domain name can reveal a lot.  But it can also not reveal a lot if the hosting provider is something like Amazon, Azure, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are many types of VPNs available, and even SSL varies in strength, so there is no clear way to do an apples-to-apples comparison. Some advertised VPNs are just an SSL tunnel anyway, but others are not. I don't believe SSL is a particularly strong tool against an ISP or nation-state level actor.
2. The URL is a Layer 7 construct, so it would be hidden from the ISP when using HTTPS (a layer 4 protocol), presuming they haven’t compromised the secured tunnel, which they are capable of doing.
3. A layer 2 or 3 VPN (IPSEC/L2TP) will send the entire DNS datagram through the tunnel, so presumably the ISP would not see it, as long as you are not using the ISP DNS servers.

Comment: My question was put on hold. I made a lot of edits to narrow down the question. Would you mind giving me your opinion on the edits?

Comment: *"presuming they haven’t compromised the secured tunnel, which they are capable of doing"* -- how would they do that if they do not control your browser or operating system to install their own root certificate?

Comment: @Arjan, Many ISPs perform certificate substutition attacks, so that they can scan inside encrypted channels. they intercept the request to establish a secure channel, and replace your keys with their own. that makes the connection between them and the remote server. as the responses come back, they just swap the certs/keys again, so you believe your browser believes it is actually connected directly to the remote system.

Comment: ....but then what security does HTTPS add to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks? And why would shady governments need [to steal root private keys](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2510950/security0/hackers-steal-ssl-certificates-for-cia--mi6--mossad.html) to create certificates that the browsers trust?

Comment: Any reference of such ISP? I really don't believe this is true.

Comment: Sorry, my conclusion is that *"I don't believe SSL is a particularly strong tool against an ISP"* and *"compromised the secured tunnel, which they are capable of doing"* are false.

Comment: Would my ISP know if the subdomain I'm visiting through HTTPS?

Comment: yes, at least in all the important ways. A subdomain usually has a unique IP address, and the destination IP is NOT encrypted (cause how would the packet know where to go?). if the subdomain shares an IP address with the root domain, then they couldn't tell which one you were accessing, but in the end, there is no real differance in the inferences you can draw from a user accessing superuser.com rather than www.superuser.com. generally speaking, if a subdomain does not have a unique IP address, then there is little differance between the subdomain and the root domain.

Comment: Ok, @FrankThomas. Are images loaded without HTTPs on their source, on a website that it IS connected to HTTPs visible to my ISP?

Comment: If the https protected page links remote images using http urls, then yes, the requests by your browser to download those images will not be ssl encrypted, and they will be observable to anyone who can see a network segment over which the packets flow.